# "npm outdated" and "npm outdated -g" don't show anything so why am I getting these warnings of deprecations?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have node.js version 12.16.3 (macOS x64), the most current LTS version. The npm version is 6.14.4, which comes as default with the node.js version already stated. My operating system is Catalina 10.15.4 (the latest version).

When I run `npm outdated` and `npm outdated -g` nothing is returned, I simply get a new line.

Yet when I run this inside of my project:

`npm init` followed by `npm i --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env`, I get these warnings:

> ```
> npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
> npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.12: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
> ```

I have tried running `npm install chokidar@^3` and I get the exact same warnings.

I have tried running `npm install chokidar@latest` and I get the exact same warnings.

I can't seem to update what I am being told to update. How can I resolve this issue?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `npm update` instead of install ? https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update

Comment: I have. I get the same warnings.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that I get the same warnings if I use `npm i --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env`.

Comment: Then I guess the warnings come from packages where the packages in question are used as dependencies . Therefore the package-maintainer is responsible for keeping its "sub" dependencies up-to-date . I am no expert on this, but I think it has also somehting to do with your `package-lock.json` file , maybe look in that direction .